# Question on a probability question

Tags: probability, self-study

I have this question for a test:
A judge is 35% sure that Tim commited burglary. The witness would lie at a probability of 0.25 if Tim is guilty but would tell the truth if Tim is innocent
What probability would the witness commit perjury? 
Is P(witness commit perjury) = 0.35*0.25 = 0.0875 ?

Comment: No I didn't! My 0.3$: The fact that judge is sure about something has nothing to do with (a) a witness, (b) the truth - doesn't it..? However this is his *prior* expectation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I believe you are correct. Let $B$ represent that Tim *is* a burglar. We are given $P(B) = 0.35$. The probability that the witness will commit perjury, call it $P(P)$, can be split into two disjoint situations:

1. The witness lies given Tim is innocent: $P(P|\overline{B})$ = 0
2. The witness lies given Tim is guilty: $P(P|B)$ = 0.25

Now we know the following:
$$
\begin{align}
P(P) &= P(P \cap B) + P(P \cap \overline{B})\\
&= p(P|B)P(B) + p(P|\overline{B})P(\overline{B})\\
&= 0.25\times .35 + 0\times .65\\
&= .0875
\end{align}
$$

Now if the question was what is the judge's posterior probability for Tim's guilt given the witness testimony, that's a different question.

Comment: For me the thoughts that judge has sound rather as a prior then posterior but it could be a matter of language...

Comment: I agree, it is the prior of the Judge's belief. As you say above, it is irrelevant to the OPs question. A more interesting question, I think, would be what is the judge's posterior belief if the witness testifies.