# Could someone help me check my answer on this probability question?

Tags: probability, self-study

The probability of A having committed a crime is 35%. B is a friend of A and will lie to help A at a probability of 25%, if A is guilty, or say the truth is A is innocent. C hates A and will lie to hurt A if A is innocent, at a probability of 30%, or say the truth is A is guilty. What is the probability that the statements of B and C contradict each other?

Scenario of guilty + scenario of innocent = (.35*.25*1)+(.65*1*.3)=0.2825

Comment: If this is for homework or an assignment could you please add the self-study tag? Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/135953/6633) which is already on hold and [this other one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/135990/6633) which I thought was deleted by the owner shortly after it was posted but apparently has been undeleted (cf. edit history).

Comment: And closely related to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/135456/question-on-a-probability-question) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not mistaken the answer is right.

First we name things:

- 'A' = A is guilty,
- 'B' = B testify A is guilty and
- 'C' = C testify A is guilty.

In the same way, we have:

- '/A' = A is innocent,
- '/B' = B testify A is innocent and
- '/C' = C testify A is innocent.

So, you're looking for the probability that B and C contradict each other, which translate as:

p(B,/C) + p(/B,C)

In case of A is guilty, p(A), this is: p(B|A)*p(/C|A) + p(/B|A)*p(C|A)

In case of A is innocent, p(/A), this is: p(B|/A)*p(/C|/A) + p(/B|/A)*p(C|/A)

But we have:

- p(/C|A) = 0
- p(C|A) = 1
- p(B|/A) = 0
- p(/B|/A) = 1

So:

p(B,/C) + p(/B,C) = p(A)[p(B|A)*0+p(/B|A)*1] + p(/A)[0*p(/C|/A)+ 1*p(C|/A)]

```
              = p(A)*p(/B|A) + p(/A)*p(C|/A)

              = 0.35*0.25+0.65*0.3 = 0.2825
```

This being said, double check, since I haven't done probabilities in a long time.

Comment: Hey tnx for your help! However, isn't p(C|/A) 0.3 from the question?

Comment: Right and thus you're right. It's fixed ;-)

Comment: Yup, tnx once agian!